# Check if QSettings is using the default value

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qsettings

is there a way that I can check whether QSettings is using the default value?

For example:

```
def setup_ui(self):
    self.user_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.user_input.setText("Input something...")
    ...
    ...

    # Check for any stored settings
    self.user_input.setText(self.settings.value("userInput", "Input something..."))


def load_settings(self):
    self.settings = QtCore.QSettings('TEST', 'My_Tool')
    input = self.settings.value("userInput", "Input something...")


def save_settings(self):
    settings = QtCore.QSettings('TEST', 'My_Tool')
    settings.setValue('userInput', self.user_input.currentText())
```

If I am re-launching my tool, there are some functions which will be using the current text string in the QLineEdit. So far, in order for me to bypass the default value, I have coded my functions as follows:

```
def test_func(self, input_text):
    if not input_text == 'Input something...':
        # Do something...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to asking if the key exists so you must use the `contains()` method:

```
if settings.contains("userInput"):
    # there is the key in QSettings

else:
    # there is no key in QSettings
```